# If all associated attributes of an intended primary key are identical, is it still a true primary key?

Tags: primary-key, duplication, architecture, uniqueidentifier, surrogate-key

I'll start with an example.  If I have a `person` table with intended surrogate primary key `Id`:

```
+----+------+------------+-------------+
| Id | name |    DoB     |     SSN     |
+----+------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | John | 1901-01-01 | 111-11-1111 |
|  2 | Jane | 1902-02-02 | 222-22-2222 |
|  3 | John | 1901-01-01 | 111-11-1111 |
+----+------+------------+-------------+
```

Note `Id`s 1 & 3 have the same attributes; They both represent the same person.

Now from what we know about the theory behind what constitutes a primary key, which I think is well summarized [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-great-primary-key-debate/):

> - The primary key must uniquely identify each record.
> - A record’s primary-key value can’t be null.
> - The primary key-value must exist when the record is created.
> - The primary key must remain stable—you    can’t change the primary-key field(s).
> - The primary key must be compact and contain the fewest possible attributes.

Consider the first bullet, "*The primary key must uniquely identify each record.*"  In my example, I suppose whether or not each `Id` does represent uniqueness depends on what's really supposed to be considered unique. A different database record? Yes.  A different person (what the records are supposed to represent)? No.

So multiple `Id`s represent what is functionally the same subject generating the data, present in 2 records.  A "two to one Id" of sorts.  I've not read anything that directly address the scenario my example illustrates, as is relates to what is or is not a PK.

1. Does this example violate the theory behind what constitutes a primary key?

   2. If not, does this example illustrate a violation of any larger principles of database architecture, or can this concept be reduced to something as simple as "duplication of data - clean it up"?

Many thanks.

Comment: The primary key must be compact and contain the fewest possible attributes it is faster with number forexqample but you can use any unique key for example uuids

Comment: I don't think this addresses my question, though I agree surrogate integers make for quicker joins, searches, anything facilitated by indexing, etc.

Comment: the problem is the **must** be, that is wring, depending on the purpose a integer is not good. a example is a distributed server where the main server is not reachabkle the whole time, when the sub server coennct the databases sychronize and that on all tables.

Comment: @mustaccio Totally agreed.  If we had a uniqueness constraint on even just `SSN`, which should be sufficient to identify a unique person, this whole issue is prevented.  But we don't.  Say we don't have that sort of control, and the data is what it is.  Is `Id` still considered a true PK?

Comment: The row is unique so yes. The situation is pretty common today when surrogate keys are used instead of modeling. Surrogate keys have their place, but far to often they are used as an excuse for lack of design.

Comment: PKs have no role in theory, CKs matter. A PK is some 1 CK you called the PK. CKs are formal & determined by FDs, which are formal & determined by what table values can arise, which are formal & determined informally per the membership criterion for a row to be in the table in a situation & the situations that can arise. Learn from a good published academic textbook. PS Words like "represent" & "identify" are vague. We have to be very clear about what is meant when we use them or read them. It is clearer to talk about 1:1 correspondences. PS It's unclear what "functionally" means here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this model is that you did not identify all candidate keys in the relation and did not enforce uniqueness of those keys you did not identify. In reality `{SSN}` and, possibly, `{Name, DoB, SomethingElse}` would constitute additional candidate keys.

Nevertheless, `Id` is still the primary key of this relation, but it does not identify the entity that you expect(ed) it to. It does not identify a "person", but something else, e.g. "an occurrence of somebody entering person's data".